# Extracting Image from a clicked ImageButton from numerous ImageButtons

Tags: android

I am trying to build an Android game in which a user will have choice to select a player from 4 available players. These Players are available as Image Buttons. I want that when a user clicks a image Button, this image will be assigned to a Bitmap variable 'PLAYER' in the Main Activity.java .
Please help me out with codes to extract the Image from clicked button and assign it to the variable PLAYER.

Any help would be grateful. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

yor can get bitmap form Imageview by using

```
Drawable dra = imageview.getDrawable();
BitmapDrawable bmp = (BitmapDrawable) dra;
Bitmap b = bmp.getBitmap();
```

and set this bitmap to your player object

method of image view.

Comment: If you look a little closer at the question he's asking about an imageButton, not an imageView. Small caveat, but different objects. I tried accessing a .getDrawable method on an imageButton and it doesn't exist.

Comment: @technoman23 - This is a 6 years old answer. You may find some changes in current api.